# Custom Routing in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Url routing with database lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912427/url-routing-with-database-lookup)

I am looking to build a CMS, This will mean that the user can add pages to the system, this will invlolve entering the URL and then the content as HTML in a Rich text editor.

How will MVC3 routing handle this? as I understand the `Controller/Action` method hits an action and returns a `View()` but if this URL `Controller/Action` exists in a database and points to content in a database

Basically I need the system to check if the route exists if not get the html from the database and display the `View()`

e.g. /Account/EditUser

In my controller I have

```
public ActionResult EditUser(){

    return View();
}

public ActionResult LoadCMS(String URL){
    // check URL exists in DB
    // get the html from db
    // return the Html as a View to the user
    // if not exists then return error page
}
```

But what do I do when I request a CMS page:

e.g. /Account/DisplayUser

in my controller there is no DisplayUser Action so go to LoadCMS
Sorry I have no idea where to start on this so I have no code to give.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @CodeCaster do you know of any demo projects for this? It seems overly complex

Answer (score 0):

> in my controller there is no DisplayUser Action so go to LoadCMS Sorry I have no idea where to start on this so I have no code to give.

As I understand this you need to display User Information using the action `DisplayUser`. So you can create an action like the one below.

```
 public ActionResult DisplayUser(string username){
    var userDetails = GetDataFromDatabase(userId);
    return View("User", userDetails);
 }
```

So this action can now be reached using the  url `www.website.com/Users/DisplayUser/yrshaikh` assuming this action is inside the `UsersController` Controller and `yrshaikh` is the username.

For more understanding you can try and understand the profile link each user has on stackoverflow, like for example mine is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1182982 here the userId is `1182982` and the controller name is `users` (this can be different if custom routing is done.)

So, I hope with this information you can get started...