# MVC routing if page url is stored in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have kind of CMS application that allows to create content pages and specify urls for them.
I'd like to let users enter any url, like:

```
/Documents/Forms/MyForm
/Documents/Manuals/MyManual
/Events/BBQThisWeek
```

Then I need to create a route that will check if a content page with the given Url exists in the DB and if yes, will route to controller that handles content pages. If not it'll continue with default route.

How do I approach this?
Thanks
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probable have to set-up a custom handler. Take a look at option three on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379558/mvc-net-routing#379823)

You could read from database on action invoker.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends Route

```
public class CustomRoute : Route
{

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if(routeData != null)
        { do some stuff on routeData... }
        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // Do the opposite of the first function
    }
}
```

edit: 
The easiest way is to extends `Route` and use base.GetRouteData then just change the data tokens 'controller' and 'action' to what you want