# C# MVC 4 View Accessing Another View By Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC, and was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to accomplish this goal. Here is an example of what I would like the url string to look like.

http://example.com/Controller?View&id&View2

http://example.com/Management?Schools&ID=20&edit

Where management is the controller, Schools is a view, and if clicking the edit link on a school it would then take you to the second view which is the edit page.

I know MVC 4 tends to keep urls in a SEO fashion, but I personally am a fan of unclean urls like the ones I posted. Any help would be great.

Comment: I believe this can be done by setting up routes to parse the URL string accordingly.

Comment: I'm thinking that you probably can't specify routing parameters after the ?, only parameters for actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that it can be done as you've described.  What you could do is pass the View name as a parameter for View2.  (ex. Schools?ID=20&View2=edit).  Then you could return that view like `return View(View2);` Check out this post on different routing examples:

[MVC Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379558/mvc-net-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Controller can return any view you want. Matching action to view name is just default

```
public ActionResult Foo(string viewName)
{
     return View(viewName);
}
```

NOTE: This is pure sample code make sure to at least validate view name is on you allow.